# How to Access QB Synced Data?

Tags: synchronization, desktop, quickbooks

I have customer they use QB then they sync using QB Sync Manager, How I can access the synced data? and the synced data we can view it online using QB online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuit offers a REST API that you can use to access data synced via Sync Manager. Essentially Sync Manager places a copy of the person's QuickBooks data into the cloud, and exposes that data via a REST API.

*But* -- you should know that Sync Manager has been *deprecated*. Intuit is no longer allowing new apps to be created for Sync Manager. If you are an existing app, you can use the existing (deprecated, legacy) APIs:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy

If you're building a new app, you should *NOT be using Sync Manager* to read QuickBooks desktop data. Instead, you should be using the QuickBooks SDK:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_qb

Also, note that Sync Manager has *absolutely nothing* to do with QuickBooks Online. QuickBooks Online is a completely separate product, with a completely separate set of APIs (the REST v3 APIs). Sync Manager *does not* enable you to access QuickBooks desktop data from within QuickBooks Online.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to be sure that all QB Desktop users sync to the same application on the cloud? and these data I can read it and change it?

Comment: Again -- syncing to the cloud via Sync Manager is *deprecated*. If you're not already using it, DO NOT use it. Instead, you'll have to build your own sync process, using the QuickBooks SDK that I linked to above.

Comment: thank you, Just I am not using QB Sync my customers already use it and I wanted to understand how it works.